# Funções Aninhadas em Python

Tags: python, funções

Como faço funções aninhadas em Python? Outra dúvida, porque sempre preciso usar o parâmetro self, sendo que já coloquei parâmetros na função?

Por exemplo, considera-se que a função gerar_individuo() já está implementada e que preciso criar uma função chamada gerar_populacao(self, individuo) como abaixo:

```
def gerar_populacao(self, individuo):
        tamanho_populacao = 100
        while(tamanho_populacao > 0):
            individuo = gerar_individuo(linha_do_tempo, linha_do_tempo, disciplinas)
```

Quando executo meu código dá o erro:

> Undefined variable 'gerar_individuo'
>
> Undefined variable  'linha_do_tempo'
>
> Undefined variable 'disciplinas'

Pelo que pude perceber, ele não está reconhecendo a função gerar_individuo() por ser uma referência externa. Como resolvo isso?

```
# aqui está todo o código:

import time
import random
import copy

class AG():

cs = []
gav = ["A01", "A02", "A03", "A04", "A05", "A06", "A07", "A08"]                              
icc = ["A02", "A08"]
lc = ["A09", "A10", "A11", "A12", "A13", "A01", "A02"]
oc = ["A14", "A15", "A16", "A17", "A18", "A19", "A20", 
"A21", "A22", "A23", "A24", "A25", "A26", "A27", "A28", "A29", "A30", 
"A31", "A32", "A33", "A34", "A35", "A36", "A37", "A38", "A39", "A40" ,
"A01", "A02", "A04", "A08"]
pcal = ["A40", "A41", "A42", "A43", "A44", "A45", "A46", "A47", "A48",
"A49", "A50", "A51", "A52", "A53", "A54", "A55", "A56", "A57", "A58", 
"A59", "A60", "A61", "A62", "A63", "A64", "A65", "A66", "A67", "A68", 
"A01", "A02", "A03", "A05", "A08"]
pc1 = ["A69", "A70", "A71", "A72", "A73", "A74", "A01", "A02", "A08"]

#codigos das disciplinas
_cs = 1101
_gav = 1102
_icc = 1103
_lc = 1104
_oc = 1105
_pcal = 1106
_pc1 = 1107

disciplinas = [_cs, _gav, _icc, _lc, _oc, _pcal, _pc1]

primeiro_ano = [1101, 1102, 1103, 1104, 1105, 1106, 1107]
segundo_ano = [2101, 2102, 2103, 2104, 2105, 2106, 2107, 2108]
terceiro_ano = [3101, 3102, 3103, 3104, 3105, 3106, 3107, 3108]
quarto_ano = [4101, 4102, 4103, 4104, 4105, 4106, 4107]

linha_do_tempo = []
TAM =  80

def __init__(self):
    self.linha_do_tempo = self.zero_list_maker(self.TAM)
    print ("Inicializando a linha do tempo...")
    print ("Linha do tempo: ", self.linha_do_tempo)

def zero_list_maker(self, length):
    listofzeros = [0] * length
    return listofzeros

def gerar_populacao(self):    
    populacao = []
    tamanho_populacao = 100
    lCount = len(self.linha_do_tempo)
    while(tamanho_populacao > 0):
        # para nao alterar as listas originais fazemos um copy delas para cada individuo
        discis = copy.deepcopy(self.disciplinas)
        linha_tempo = copy.deepcopy(self.linha_do_tempo)
        randDisc = []
        next1 = False
        for i in range(0, lCount-1):
            if(len(discis) > 0):
                position = random.randint(0,lCount-1)
                disc = random.choice(discis)
                if(linha_tempo[i] == 0 and linha_tempo[i+1] == 0):
                    linha_tempo[position] = disc
                    randDisc.append(disc)
                    discis.remove(disc)
                    next1 = True
                elif(next1):
                    linha_tempo[position] = disc
                    randDisc.append(disc)
                    discis.remove(disc)
                    next1 = False
                else:
                    break
            populacao.append(linha_tempo)
        tamanho_populacao -= 1
    return populacao
```

ag = AG()
populacao = ag.gerar_populacao()
print(populacao)
primeiro_individuo = populacao[0]
print('\n\n\nPrimeira pessoa:\n', primeiro_individuo)

Comment: O problema não é a função, é a variável `linha_tempo` que nao está definida. E porque a repete? Self é se essas funções pertencerem a um objecto/classe. Estao dentro de uma class?

Comment: Entendi amigo =) sim, está tudo dentro de um class apenas. É assim: fiz uma função gerar individuo com o código que você fez, como está acima, onde passo por parâmetro a linha_do_tempo que foi inicializada com 80 posições de zero:

Comment: linha_do_tempo = [0] * 80

Comment: essa funcao gerar individuo retorna alguma coisa? se fizer print individuo depois disso vai ter aquela que trabalhou

Comment: mas devia declarar linha tempo dentro da funcao gerar populacao, antes do while

Comment: e a lista de disciplinas, que contém todas as disciplinas. Distribuí randomicamente elas, conforme seu código, na linha do tempo. Agora preciso gerar uma lista de individuos, como por ex. 100 linhas do tempo diferentes e armazenar em uma lista.

Comment: secalhar seria mais facil se colocasse todo o codigo relevante para o podermos ajudar

Comment: Joia, farei isso então em outra pergunta =)

Comment: Pronto amigo, editei a minha pergunta ali em cima, e adicionei todo o código. Tentei fazer um while() com o tamanho da população e imprimir o resultado, mas não gerou nada xD

Comment: Porque está a chamar `gerar_populacao` com dois `linha_do_tempo`?

Comment: Se eu remover o primeiro parâmetro linha_do_tempo não funciona, gera um erro dizendo que o parâmetro self não foi inicializado. Aparece o seguinte erro: No value for argument 'disciplinas' in method call

Comment: Estou fazendo o projeto no c9.io por ser tcc preferi fazer na nuvem. Como faço para referenciar você no meu tcc? Irei agradece-lo pela ajuda!

Comment: Não é preciso @Allan. Eu sou de portugal, aqui já está tarde, hora de dormir. Amanha no trabalho volto aqui e se não tiver ainda solução resolvemos este problema. Pode ser?

Comment: Sim amigo, pode deixar! Quanto ao fato de você ser de Portugal não há problema, porque meu embasamento teórico é em um artigo de uma Profª Dra. aí de Portugal =) Profª Paula Amaral da Universidade de Lisboa :D bom descanso amigo, obrigado mesmo pela ajuda!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41402/discussion-between-miguel-and-allan).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Allan aqui vai. O problema é que quando estamos a aceder a propriedades/metodos dentro da class temos de usar o prefixo/argumento `self` que é para referirmos que o metodo/propriedade pertence áquela classe. Quando digo:

`metodo = função (def my_func():)` ex: `zero_list_maker`

`propriedade = variaveis de instancia` ex: linha_do_tempo, que depois dentro dos metodos referenciamo-la assim: `self.linha_do_tempo`:

Parti do principio que cada 1 dos 100 `tamanho_populacao` deve armazenar o que resultado de cada loop do ciclo for:

```
import time
import random
import copy

class AG():

    cs = []
    gav = []                              
    icc = []
    lc = []
    oc = []
    pcal = []
    pc1 = []

    disciplinas = []

    primeiro_ano = []
    segundo_ano = []
    terceiro_ano = []
    quarto_ano = []

    linha_do_tempo = []
    TAM =  80

    def __init__(self):
        self.icc = ["A02", "A08"]
        self.lc = ["A09", "A10", "A11", "A12", "A13", "A01", "A02"]
        self.oc = ["A14", "A15", "A16", "A17", "A18", "A19", "A20", "A21", "A22", "A23", "A24", "A25", "A26", "A27", "A28", "A29", "A30", "A31", "A32", "A33", "A34", "A35", "A36", "A37", "A38", "A39", "A40", "A01", "A02", "A04", "A08"]
        self.pcal = ["A40", "A41", "A42", "A43", "A44", "A45", "A46", "A47", "A48", "A49", "A50", "A51", "A52", "A53", "A54", "A55", "A56", "A57", "A58", "A59", "A60", "A61", "A62", "A63", "A64", "A65", "A66", "A67", "A68", "A01", "A02", "A03", "A05", "A08"]
        self.pc1 = ["A69", "A70", "A71", "A72", "A73", "A74", "A01", "A02", "A08"]
        self.gav = ["A01", "A02", "A03", "A04", "A05", "A06", "A07", "A08"]

        self.primeiro_ano = [1101, 1102, 1103, 1104, 1105, 1106, 1107]
        self.segundo_ano = [2101, 2102, 2103, 2104, 2105, 2106, 2107, 2108]
        self.terceiro_ano = [3101, 3102, 3103, 3104, 3105, 3106, 3107, 3108]
        self.quarto_ano = [4101, 4102, 4103, 4104, 4105, 4106, 4107]

        _cs = 1101
        _gav = 1102
        _icc = 1103
        _lc = 1104
        _oc = 1105
        _pcal = 1106
        _pc1 = 1107

        self.disciplinas = [_cs, _gav, _icc, _lc, _oc, _pcal, _pc1]

        self.linha_do_tempo = self.zero_list_maker(self.TAM)
        print ("Inicializando a linha do tempo...")
        print ("Linha do tempo: ", self.linha_do_tempo)

    def zero_list_maker(self, length):
        listofzeros = [0] * length
        return listofzeros

    def gerar_populacao(self):    
        populacao = []
        tamanho_populacao = 100
        lCount = len(self.linha_do_tempo)
        while(tamanho_populacao > 0):
            # para nao alterar as listas originais fazemos um copy delas para cada individuo
            discis = copy.deepcopy(self.disciplinas)
            linha_tempo = copy.deepcopy(self.linha_do_tempo)
            randDisc = []
            positions = []
            for i in range(0, lCount-1):
                if(len(discis) > 0):
                    position = random.randint(0,lCount-2)
                    disc = random.choice(discis)
                    if(linha_tempo[position] == 0 and linha_tempo[position+1] == 0):
                        linha_tempo[position] = disc
                        linha_tempo[position+1] = disc
                        randDisc.append(disc)
                        discis.remove(disc)
                else:
                    break
            populacao.append(linha_tempo)
            tamanho_populacao -= 1
        return populacao


ag = AG()
populacao = ag.gerar_populacao()
print(populacao)
primeiro_individuo = populacao[0]
print('\n\n\nPrimeira pessoa:\n', primeiro_individuo)
```

Apaguei alguns imports que não estava a usar e os comentários para o código não ficar muito extenso aqui.

Comment: Perfeito mesmo Miguel! É exatamente isso mesmo! A única coisa que eu estava a pensar é o seguinte: agora que fui ver que na verdade durante a inicialização, perceba que quando as disciplinas são distribuídas na linha_do_tempo (que foi inicializada com zeros), as disciplinas são colocadas nas primeiras posições da linha_do_tempo. Na verdade as disciplinas devem ser distribuídas exatamente como está, mas em posições aleatórias da linha_do_tempo.

Comment: Haa sim entendi, vou editar @Allan

Comment: Feito @Allan em cima

Comment: Não sei se consegui explicar direito, eh que minha net parou de funcionar aqui:

Comment: agora que vi haha isso mesmo, bem isso que eu estava falando ;-) na distribuição dos indivíduos é obrigatório ficar um em seguida do outro, por ex:

Comment: Tem que ficar assim: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1102, 1102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1107, 1107, 0, 1103, 1103, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1105, 1105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1106, 1106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1104, 1104, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1101, 1101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: Ao invés de ficar assim: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1107, 0, 0, 1103, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1104, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: Porque trata-se de um horário escolar, então as disciplinas são distribuídas uma em seguida da outra. O índice do vetor representa 50 min que cada aula dura =)

Comment: Eu agora fiz o seguinte, para ficar mais fácil de visualizar, criei códigos para as disciplinas, irei alterar o código pra você dar uma olhada ;-)

Comment: Alterei, está ali na pergunta! A única coisa que mudou é que criei um código para cada disciplina: _cs = 1101 e assim por diante. O vetor de disciplinas ficou assim: disciplinas = [_cs, _gav, _icc, _lc, _oc, _pcal, _pc1]

Comment: Aqui: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41402/discussion-between-miguel-and-allan

Comment: Cuidado vocês dois com uma coisa - **em Python não se deve declarar listas no corpo de uma casse**: a mesma lista vai ser compartilahda por todas as instâncias da classe. Se cada instância da classe deve ter suas próprias coleções, elas devem ser inicializadas dentro do método `__init__`.

Comment: É verdade, já estou a trabalhar em otimizar isso. Obgado @jsbueno